# How do I calculate my average page coverage for my Black toner cartridges based on the pages Yielded?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, printing

This should be a simple formula, but the logic is escaping me.

Let's take an example cartridge that Yields 4,000 pages (at the industry standard page coverage of 5%).
This hypothetical cartridge ran empty after printing 3,333 pages.

How do I calculate the average page coverage of the jobs I printed using this cartridge?

Thanks

(I plan on using this answer for a spreadsheet formula, however I don't require the answer to be as a formula)

Comment: since 4000 * 0.05 = 1 cart , & 3333 * 'x' = 1 cart. || so 4000 * 0.05 = 3333 * 'x'  || 'x' = 4000 * 0.05 / 3333 = 0.0600060... || ans = 6.00060%

Comment: Thanks p._phidot_ I appreciate the way you walked through the process.

Comment: Wish I knew why somebody downvoted my question, did it lack clarity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4,000 divided by 3,333 times 0.05 = 0.06. So your average page coverage was 6%.